# Cordova 3.5 build Android get error with command line on mac

Tags: android, cordova

I use cordova 3.5 first time, try to build android apk with it, but get below error during build apk package get error like below, can't find where is wrong, can any one tell me where is wrong? thanks.
    -pre-compile:
     [echo] Set jars path to: /Users/zinch-    cn/Project/SchoolLibrary/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar

```
-compile:
[javac] Compiling 6 source files to /Users/zinch-cn/Project/SchoolLibrary/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
[javac] /Users/zinch-cn/Project/SchoolLibrary/platforms/android/src/com/zinch/SchoolLibrary/.java:25: <identifier> expected
[javac] public class  extends CordovaActivity
[javac]             ^
[javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 4 seconds

/Users/zinch-cn/Project/SchoolLibrary/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/Users/zinch-cn/Project/SchoolLibrary/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /Users/zinch-cn/Project/SchoolLibrary/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Comment: it looks like there's no class name in the class that extends CordovaActivity

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample mistake on create new project with cordova,

```
cordova create abc com.example.abc ABC
```

abc would same with com.example.abc, if the project will be created no error, when you build app would show strange error like above. hope this can help someone.