# Error while adding the Android platform to a cordova project

Tags: cordova

I started a fresh Cordova project via:

```
cordova create project com.pro.ject Project
```

When I added:

```
cordova platform add android
```

I got the error:

```
Downloading cordova library for android...
Download complete
Creating android project...

C:\Users\myself\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_modules\q\q.
js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\Users\myself\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\lib\check_
reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (C:\Users\myself\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin
\node_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at C:\Users\myself\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_modul
es\q\q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\myself\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\
bin\node_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\myself\.cordova\lib\and
roid\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at C:\Users\myself\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_modul
es\q\q.js:574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\myself\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\nod
e_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5
```

At the same time Eclipse can successfully create phonegap project and compile them towards android but the cordova.exe doesn't recognise the projects created by Eclipse as Cordova projects.

Comment: Have you installed cordova globally?

npm install -g cordova

Comment: Same error as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550917/cordova-3-5-build-android-get-error-with-command-line-on-mac/25551650#25551650

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add both

\android-sdks\tools

and

\android-sdks\platform-tools

to your path and it works

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [this dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670809/user670809)

Here is sample mistake on create new project with cordova,

```
cordova create abc com.example.abc ABC
```

abc would same with com.example.abc, if the project will be created no error, when you build app would show strange error like above. hope this can help someone.